# Querying multi-field in Elasticsearch for Exact string match

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a string field in Elasticsearch with following mapping

```
"part_number":{"type":"string"}
```

Since I wanted to do exact-string-search on this field, I added an extra field, which is `not analyzed`

```
{
  "properties": {
    "part_number": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I query for part_number.raw field, Elasticsearch returns results.

```
_search?fields=part_number.raw&q=part_number:abc-000123
```

But how to query on `part_number.raw` field. I want to do something like

```
_search?fields=part_number.raw&q=part_number.raw:abc-000123
```

But this query returns empty hits.

I am using python elastic client.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're querying the `part_number.raw` field like that you need to send an [exact match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names) query, i.e. surrounded with escaped double quotes.

```
_search?fields=part_number.raw&q=part_number.raw:\"abc-000123\"
                                                  ^           ^
                                                  |           |
                                                add double quotes
```